# How/where to include and read build information in an EAR?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, build

I've been trying to come up with a clean way to include and display in a webpage build information from an EAR (containing the web app war).

My first instinct is to put the bulls metadata in the ear META-INF/MANIFEST.MF file.  But the chance I have with that is that the ear's manifest is not part of the classpath and consequently there is no way to read it without using file operations - generally a no no in a JEE container.

Another option is to add the bulls info to the war manifest, but that isn't giving me the necessary info on the EAR.

Lastly, I could have the build process create a properties file in a jar in the EAR/lib folder, but that feels very wrong as well... Creating a lib on the fly like that screams poor practice.

Is there a clean/property way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

In Java EE 6 and newer you can place `<env-entry>` elements in the EAR's application.xml file.

Therefore you can place whatever additional metadata you need into one or more `<env-entry>` sections and then load the values either via `@Resource` injection or good old fashioned JNDI lookups.